# Find and orthogonal Q

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find an orthogonal $Q$ so that $Q^{-1}AQ=D$ where $D$ denotes the diagonalised form of A with eigenvalues on the diagonal.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Okay so when the eigenvalue is $0$ i end up finding the eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$ as

$$
span(\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix})$$

From here I can't form a orthogonal matrix $Q$ because the basis of the eigenspace for $eigenvalue=0$ aren't orthogonal to each other :(
 Help me out pls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those you chose are indeed eigenvectors, but there are many more you can choose from, and here we want to pick **orthonormal** ones (in order for the matrix to be orthogonal).

For example

> $$v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,-1),\quad w=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}(1/2,-1,1/2)$$

Of course where the Spectral Theorem kicks in, is to guarantee that any two eigenspaces are orthogonal, so that you can indeed form a - whole - orthogonal matrix.